# PPA does not have a release file

Tags: apt, ppa

I'm trying to install Oracle Java 7 from Webupd8team ppa by following instructions from [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html).

I have it installed on one of my other systems using the same ppa. But now when I try to `apt update` after adding the ppa it says the following

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: I think this was a transient issue, Both files `Release` and `Release.gpg` are [there](http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/xenial/) and updated on 02-Mar-2017 . Would you recheck if you still have the same issue?